# How do I adjust intensity between several files using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, gis, scikit-image

I have a some *GeoTIFF* images and I need adjust the intensity between them.

I tried several ways using *OpenCV* and *SkImage* (normalization, histogram match, equalization) but I didn't succeed. In this case I can't merge the final images. I have to equalize them and export each file individually.

I will show the first example using 2 files. But I need to do this to about 75 images. The raw images are shown below and it's easy to see the intensity difference between the two images.

To read the data I am using *OpenCV*:

```py
img1 = cv2.imread(r'1.tif', flags=(cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE + cv2.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL))

img2 = cv2.imread(r'2.tif', flags=(cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE + cv2.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL))
```

_

[image]

_

Using *QGIS*, I can do the process manually, but I spend a lot of time.

Below is the approximate expected result:

_

[image]

_

I want to ask for help on finding a way forward, a tip, anything to help with this.

Comment: You could try adjusting them from one to the next by matching mean and standard deviation (i.e. brightness and contrast). See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Comment: Thanks for the site, but I tried and didn't work well. Some pictures are good, but many files don`t have the progress of intensity.

Comment: How about sharing the images so we can try some experiments?

Comment: HI Mark, thank you. Follow the link https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av58o7S5NWNXjP0iDrPOFWc4cJMaZw?e=fWcvev